# Existe um maneira melhor de inserir uma option no select com jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-select, inserir, html-option

Queria saber se existe uma melhor forma de inserir um `option` no `select` com jquery.

Exemplo:

```
<select name="municipio_evento" id="municipio_evento">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">ACEGUA</option>
<option value="2">AGUA SANTA</option>
<option value="3">AGUDO</option>
<select>
```

Sei que posso fazer dessa maneira:

```
$('#municipio_evento').append('<option value="4">AGUAS CLARAS</option>');
```

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão ou ideia agradeço.

Comment: Essa maneira funciona bem. Mais interessante seria saber como planeia usar este código. Só aí dá para dizer se existe maneira melhor. Mas não vejo problema como está.

Comment: A maneira que quero utilizar é dinâmica ou seja pode vir apenas um insert de option ou vários. O fato é que inserir uma string desse tamanho não parece ser a melhor forma.

Comment: O jQuery é assim. O MooTools nesse aspecto é mais "JavaScript" usando `createElement` e juntando-lhe propriedades. Se vai usar jQuery essa maneira funciona. Talvez seja bom criar uma função que dá `return '<option value="'+valor+'">'+nome+'</option>'`. Se quiser um exemplo concreto tem de colocar mais código para o exemplo ser mais acertado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode instanciar uma classe de Option do DOM.

```
 var option = new Option('TESTE','4');
 $('#municipio_evento').append(option);
```

Você pode testar funcionando no JSFiddle, segue o link
[Teste Option Append](http://jsfiddle.net/markomafs/w8o39b96/) :

Obs.: recomendo utilizar isso dentro de uma function para facilitar uma futura reutilização.

Comment: O ficou muito simples só passar text e value!

Answer (score 3):

A resposta mais correta é um grande **depende**.

A forma que você expôs é basicamente o padrão. [Quase todos os exemplos da documentação oficial](http://api.jquery.com/append/) fazem basicamente isso, usam o método `append` para transformar strings em elementos e adicioná-los a um elemento pai de uma tacada só.

Outra alternativa é primeiro criar o elemento, depois inserir:

```
var opcao = $("<option value='foo'>bar</option>");
$("#teuSeletor").append(opcao);
```

Que tende a ser mais legível e organizado, quando há mais código envolvido.

A questão de qual forma é melhor depende do contexto no qual você vai usar. Se tudo que você vai fazer é adicionar uma opção uma única vez e pronto, não é problema fazer como você já está fazendo. Se você vai utilizar estruturas de repetição e/ou gerar as opções dinamicamente, a segunda forma costuma deixar seu código mais fácil de testar e manter.

Comment: Queria reduzir o número de linhas e desta forma acho que código deve ficar melhor para debug entre outras melhorias, mas fica mais divido sera que não tem uma forma de eu passar só value e text

Comment: O melhor código para depurar não é o que tem menos linhas, mas sim o que tem linhas mais simples de entender e idealmente apenas uma instrução por linha ;)

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal e você não me entendeu, o que quis dizer é que código que você descreveu deve ficar 'melhor para debug entre outras melhorias', mas eu queria reduzir numero de linhas, na verdade como comentei antes queria só passar o value e text.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a melhor maneira de trabalhar com grandes listas em HTML + JS é usar um JSON que pode, inclusive, estar em algum arquivo externo, mais fácil de alterar depois, algo do tipo:

```
<select name="municipio_evento" id="municipio_evento"></select>
<script>

    html = "";
    obj = {
        "1" : "ACEGUA",
        "2": "AGUA SANTA",
        "3" : "AGUDO"
    }
    for(var key in obj) {
        html += "<option value=" + key  + ">" +obj[key] + "</option>"
    }
    document.getElementById("municipio_evento").innerHTML = html;

</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado.